# laravel external folder definition

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, directory, laravel-routing

My folders structure like this: app, bootstrap, public, vendor

But, I want to create another folder in there and put some php files (irrelevant with laravel).

For example wordpress.

---

i.e.
I have a web site with `laravel` and I want a `wordpress` blog in subfolder to.

I created folder names like "blog". But when I access `domain.com/blog` `laravel` presents an error.

I need to tell `laravel`, blog folder is not yours.

---

How can I do that?

Comment: This question makes little sense in its current form. Because I doubt you're asking simply how to create a directory. Because to place files inside a directory in a Laravel project folder you just **create the directory and put the files in it**.

Comment: Nope, think like this: I have a web site with laravel and I want to wordpress blog in subfolder to. I create folder names like "blog". But when I access http://domain.com/blog laravel make the error. I need to ask laravel, blog folder is not yours.

Comment: Laravel doesn't care about other folders, because in the `.htaccess` file that comes with it it instructs Apache to serve existing files and folders as such (if you're using another web server you should specify that). But the problem is different, the root folder from where the Laravel app on `domain.com` is served is `public`, so your `blog` directory must be in `public` for it to be served (or at least have a symbolic link from `/path/to/laravel/blog` to `/path/to/laravel/public/blog`).

Comment: If you want to use the subdirectory `/blog` approach you can use this [Wordpress Support Article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) to help you set it up. It is however easier to just use a subdomain like `blog.domain.com`, which has it's own root directory, different from the Laravel one, and doesn't need any special setup to work. And as a clarification (since people seem to bring this up sometimes) from a SEO standpoint [it is equivalent to the folder approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MswMYk05tk).

Comment: I put folder blog in public. And I try access domain.com/public/blog but doesn't work. What is wrong, I realy don't understand.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it return an error, 404 not found, what? You can't expect us to guess what's not working if you give no details. Also, have you read the article I linked to?

Comment: Error is 404 not found. I don't care wordpress, I just want to create sub folder and access it.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: I use apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(chat)
```

and it's work